# Java List has a method to add multiple elements at a position, but I can't find a method to remove multiple elements at a position

Tags: java, list, collections

There is `List.addAll(position, collection)` but I can't find a corresponding `List.<remove>(position, <range>)`, whatever the wording of  and the way  is specified would be. In `ArrayList`, there is `removeRange(position, positionAfter)`, but not in `List`.

Removing an interval from a list can be O(1) in many list types, removing elements one by one would be O(n) and miss that ability. Converting a general `List` to a type that supports range removal would also be O(n) and miss the chance.

Is there any way to remove a range of values from a general `List` in a way that the `List` implementations can optimize for this?

Comment: What is your question? Right now you have just stated a fact, that the `List` interface doesn't have something, and you're right, it doesn't.

Comment: `List` indeed has no `removeRange`. What are you asking exactly? Note that ["why is it not a certain way" is not a good question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293815/5133585)

Comment: You can also use `listIterator(startIndex)` and then remove from there. The complexity of doing that may vary depending on your `List` implementation (I can't post this in an answer since your question was closed now).

Comment: @dan1st but that's not a good way of removing multiple items, because each remove is done independently, which is inefficient in the case of removing from the start/middle of an ArrayList because all the elements are shifted down multiple times. `subList(...).clear()` does just one shift, however many elements you remove.

Comment: @AndyTurner this depends on the list you are working with. For example, for `LinkedList`, this would save the cost of looking up the cost of navigating to the element to remove each time. `subList().clear()` is great but there may be specific lists (especially with custom `List` implementations) that don't optimize well for that. It all depends on the type of list you are dealing with.

Comment: @dan1st even for LinkedList, it's less efficient because you update the prev/next pointers for nodes you immediately delete.

Comment: With more efficient, I meant more efficient that deleting all using remove(int) or similar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`List#subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-)

The `List` method `subList` returns a view of a subrange of the list, backed by the same data: Alterations made to the sublist are reflected in the original.

So you can use `subList` and `clear` to remove a block of elements from a mutable list:

```
>>> List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>(List.of(10,20,30,40,50,60));
values ==> [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
>>> values.subList(3,5).clear()
>>> values
values ==> [10, 20, 30, 60]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there may be some lists that don't implement efficient removal with [`subList` as described by khelwood](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77365310/10871900), you can use an iterator in cases like that. The time complexity of that may vary depending on your list implementation.

```java
List<T> yourList = ...;//TODO
Iterator<T> it = yourList.listIterator(yourStartIndex);
for(int i=0; i<numberOfElementsToRemove && it.hasNext(); i++){
    it.next();
    it.remove();
}
```

Here, the `List#listIterator(int)` method creates a `ListIterator` at the position where you want to start.

There, it removes as many elements as you want to remove. This may not lead to best possible performance but it doesn't need to look up the position of each element to remove seperately.